# Countdown timer field with a scheduler module

Tags: javascript

i am using https://drupal.org/project/field_countdown and https://drupal.org/project/scheduler modules.

I have added field_countdown field to my content type 'items'.
I have enabled scheduler for my content type 'items'.

When i am creating a node, i have to choose a date for field_countdown (it shows jQuery timer countdown until set date), also i have to set Scheduler date after that. So you have to set 2 dates instead of one, because these modules are not working together.

So i want to fill only 1 field instead of 2 of them, in my case its a field_countdown and copy its options to a scheduler input.

[image: You can see on the image that i have to fill same info 2 times]

I've tried jquery without success:

```
(function($) {
    // jquery timer
    Drupal.behaviors.MyTimer = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            // This code will run, on load, even in overlay!!!!!!
            var timerDate = $('#input-id').val();
            alert(timerDate);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

But js console says that `timerDate` is undefined. I am using overlay and bartik theme for administration pages.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a good place to start:

http://code.zeurois.com/jquery-countdown/configurator/new/-/tpl/t105-900